# How to connect to web service running on Android device from a another computer on the same LAN?

Tags: android, rest, service, portforwarding

Basically my dev machine and my phone are on the same (WiFi) network, and I need to be able to send and receive JSON to a service running on localhost on the device from my PC (Im working on a mobile app which has a component that runs as a service locally). Ive looked at port forwarding from Chrome but could not get it to work. Anyone got this to work on a Mac?

Comment: If you want to do port forwarding, use ADB or SSH.  If you want to run an ordinary server, run it on all interfaces or the wifi one, not the loopback interface to which "localhost" refers.

Comment: I dont have control over what interface/ports the component listens on since its from a third-party. It is hardcoded to listen to localhost on a specific port number.

Comment: That's not really true. If it is your app, yoy can trivially change such details, even in a compiled library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this:

- Used "adb forward tcp:LOCALPORT tcp:REMOTEPORT on my desktop machine to forward the port the service is listening on (REMOTEPORT) to a local port on my desktop (LOCALPORT)
- The service I was trying to talk to needed additional auth headers which I wasn't adding when testing with curl. I retrieved the key needed for the auth header using 'adb logcat' (since my app writes it to the console on startup). To add the auth header to each request I used a Chrome extension ([Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)) to craft requests with the auth headers added automatically.
- I can now POST requests to localhost:LOCALPORT using Postman in Chrome on my desktop and see the responses as JSON.

FYI, Im using Couchbase Lite on the device and was trying to figure out how to talk to it to run database queries.

Answer (score 0):

If your dev machine and your phone are on the same subnet of your wifi network, you should just be able to test using static IPs.  Port forwarding is not necessary (and won't help unless you use your WAN IP or set up a DNS service).

Basically, if for example your server has a local IP of 192.168.1.17, use that as the endpoint on your Android application.  If working the other way around, there are some IP tool apps to help you get the IP of your android device.

Comment: As mentioned, the service is running on localhost (127.0.0.1) so can't connect from an external IP directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the connection while developing, simply using your phone's ip to setup socket would be convenient.

Sending Script

```
import socket

HOST = ''    # device ip
PORT = ''    # your service's listening port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
with open("data.json", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
    s.send(data)
    s.close()
```

It's almost the same with receiving.